# Transfer data from android framework to app

Tags: android, android-framework

I want to transfer data from system_server process to an app. I have successfully tried it using socket programming. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Better way in the case of Android is to transfer data using Binder. To perform data exchange between processes you need to specify an interface using AIDL language.